# Denavit Hartenberg parameters - 3DOF articulated manipulator

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics, dh-parameters, robotics-toolbox

I am trying to solve a forward kynematics problem for a 3DOF manipulator.

I am working with the Robotics Toolbox for MatLab created by Peter Corke and after calculte the DH parameters and introduce them into MatLab to compute the fordward kynematics the plotted robot is not what it should be.

I guess I made some mistakes calculating the DH parameters.

Attached is the file where you can see what are the DH frames calculated for each joint and the DH parameters for each frame.

Anyone could give me a clue whether this is the correct answer?

Here is the image with the frames calculated by me.
[image]

And here the robot I get from Matlab (using the Robotics Toolbox by P.Corke)
[image]

Comment: Are these all rotational joints? Are you trying to solve for YZ?

Comment: yes, they are all rotational joints. The red frames were calculated by me as a solution, but I think something is wrong there...    What do you mean solve for YZ?

Comment: I meant XYZ...............

Comment: What I am trying to do is draw the frames for the 3 joints and calculate from them the theta, d, a and alfa parameters. I am still not sure what you mean solving it for XYZ, sorry!

Comment: What coordinates of the end-effector would you like to control? X Y and Z or some combination of position and orientation?

Comment: Sorry, my bad for some reason I had the impression you are trying to do inverse kineamtics...

Comment: By now I am trying to obtain DH parameters to solve then the forward kynematics and inverse kynematics problem. But I am not sure whether I have drawn the frames (the red ones) in their right position. Thanks!

Comment: The frames seem be ok but the tabel did not match them...

Comment: You can't represent this with DH parameters because $z_2$ cannot be generated by rotating about $x_1$. You could add a fake unactuated joint or modify the DH transformation for link 2 so that you have a y-component $L_1$ instead of the typical x-component ($a$).

Comment: I can't see why you can't rotating about x_1 to obtain z_2. First rotate S_1 about z_1, displace L_2 and then rotate about x_1 to obtain z_2. Isn't that right?

Comment: I did a similar simulation using SolidWorks:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crJXUlzJ918

Comment: anyone found the solution ?
i have this problem and i can't resolve in matlab robotic toolbox

Answer (score 4):

I defined the robot using your (assumed standard) DH parameters:

```
>> robot = SerialLink([pi/2 1 0 pi/2; pi/2 1 0 -pi/2; pi/2 1 1 0])
robot = 
noname:: 3 axis, RRR, stdDH, fastRNE                             
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| j |     theta |         d |         a |     alpha |    offset |
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1|         q1|          1|          0|     1.5708|          0|
|  2|         q2|          1|          0|    -1.5708|          0|
|  3|         q3|          1|          1|          0|          0|
+---+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Note that for revolute joints the value of theta is ignored, not it is replaced with the values q1 to q3 in the printed table above.

To plot the robot at this configuration:

```
>> robot.plot([pi/2 pi/2 pi/2])
```

shows a robot somewhat different to your diagram.  I think your DH parameters are not correct.

I really don't like DH parameters.  Looking at your diagram I can write the forward kinematics as a string of simple transformations expressed in the world coordinate frame

```
>> DHFactor('Rz(q1)Tz(L0)Rz(q2)Ty(L1)Tx(L2)Ry(q3)Tx(L3)')
  .
  .
  .
DH(q1, 0, 0, 0).DH(q2, L0, L2, -90).DH(q3, L1, L3, 90)
```

where the parameters of the DH() functions are theta, d, a, alpha.

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
Theta = [pi/2, -pi/2, -pi/2];
D     = [L0,    L2,    L1  ];
A     = [0,     0,     L3  ];
Alfa  = [pi/2, -pi/2,  0   ];
```

with

```
 T = [cos(theta) -sin(theta)*cos(alpha) sin(theta)*sin(alpha) a*cos(theta); 
      sin(theta) cos(theta)*cos(alpha) -cos(theta)*sin(alpha) a*sin(theta);
      0          sin(alpha)             cos(alpha)            d;
      0          0                      0                     1];
```

i added the matrix to make sure the differences do not come from the differences in the DH and modified DH paramters.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Can you try your parameters with the Robotics Toolbox by Peter Corke? I have similar results when I create a SerialLink with yours. The robot plotted no resembles the one in the picture, and I am not sure why. (I choosed L1, L2, and L3 = 1).

Comment: Sorry, I do not have Robotics Toolbox installed. Do you use the 'standard' parameter when you define the links?

Comment: yes. I use the stdDH. I attached at the first message an image with the robot I get from Matlab with my parameters. The one get using yours, is quite similar.

Comment: Do you have to initialize with the Dh parameters? can you initialize using the transformation matrix I have copy pasted?

Comment: Assuming that the global fram is displayed in the image, it seems that you are building up the robot in an inverted order. The first joint connected to the XYZ frame is translated in two dimentions, but the table only has two translateion (a and d) for the last frame...

Comment: I think the links are connected right. I have made some experiments trying to introduce them in an inverted order but the robot I get is different from the image too. Are you sure that the frames are ok?? I am not sure about the second frame... this is the first robot with that shape I try to solve using DH parameters, and seeing a frame "floating" in the air is an strange thing for me...

Comment: Frame 2 floating in the air is fine. Seems strange however, that the first frame attached to the world coordinate system in the matlab image has both an a and a d offset. In the table there is only a d offset...

Comment: Try replacing L3 with a larger number e.g. 10 to see which element on the image corresponds to it

Comment: q3 corresponds with the las joint, the one which forms an L at the end of the manipulator. In the Matlab plot there is only "d" for the first frame, that is the length from the base until the second joint (L0).

Comment: Why do you have 4 sets of DH parameters for a 3 DOF manipulator?

Comment: First one I used to plot my world frame in matlab and I forgot about it...Sorry, made the change